# Uploading image via ASP.NET Core Web API gets corrupted

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-10, windows-server-2022

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core Web API that posts an image and saves it to the server.

When I using Visual Studio, it works fine and saves the image in the `Pics` directory.

But when uploading it to Windows VPS, it saves the file, but there is no size - it means it's corrupted.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<ImageFile>> PostImage([FromForm] ImageFile image)
{
    try
    {
        // string Pic = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image.AttImage.FileName);
        string path = Path.Combine(wwrootPath + "/Pics/" + RandomString(32) + ".jpg");

        // Logger.LogError("Omar1 : " + path);
        if (image.AttImage == null)
            return null;

        using (var filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            _= image.AttImage.CopyToAsync(filestream);
        }
                
        image.ImagePath = path;
        image.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // Logger.LogError("Omar2 : "+path);

        _context.Images.Add(image);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return image;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Logger.LogError(ex.Message+" : "+ex.InnerException);
        return null; 
    }
}
```

[image]

I searched for many solutions and give the `Pics` directory full control permission but the problem persists.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why are you calling `CopyToAsync` and discarding the Task instead of awaiting it?

Comment: @madreflection Cause it may take long time with response and let them do the save in background

Comment: What you've done doesn't cause it to run in the background. And you *can't* run it in the background because you're immediately saving it to the database. You *must* wait for it to finish.

Comment: @madreflection Thanks thats right it s worked very nicely. but why it is worked on local iis and even when deployed it to asp web hosting

Comment: Are you saying the code you posted was able to save the image when running locally via VS IISExpress? The images were intact and you could view them? But when you uploaded the code to a web hosting service, the images save with 0 size?

Comment: @TimJarosz Ok  I with you with that. but I also deployed it to asp web hosting and it worked good. but when i used windows vps i has this issue .

Comment: Ok, so now you're on a window Virtual Private Server (VPS)? If you control the server, what user is the IIS Application Pool running as? Does that user account have full access to the path where the API is trying save to? Did you configure IIS on the VPS?